# Predictive Text on ios keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

I need to *show predictive text on top of keyboard* in below iOS 8. I am using iOS 7. I have seen Android keyboard which comes with predictive text.

Is there any way to do so in iOS without installing any App for showing predictive text.

Comment: it is a in-build feature of iOS 8 keyboard.

Comment: if you are using an iPhone and the predective text isn't shown, then there are 2 possible reasons.. 1. the text you are typing cannot be predicted, 2. you disabled keyboard assistance. go to settings-> general -> keyboard and enable "auto correction"

Comment: @iDev thank you for your reply. I am using iOS 7 in my app. Sorry I should mentioned it in question. I edited my question.

Comment: @AnanthaSharma auto correction is already enabled. Still i am not able to see the text.

Comment: iOS7 gives predictive text when user types, but it is not above the keyboard like android, the predictions will appear below the text in the focussed field.